# Understanding the proof by induction of Leibnitz formula: Why the derivative of a sum be the sum of derivative?

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove by induction: if $n \geq 1$ and $f^{(n)}(x_0)$ and $g^{(n)}(x_0)$ exist, then so does $(fg)^{(n)}(x_0)$ and 
>   $$P_n:(fg)^{(n)} (x_0) = \sum_{m=0}^{n} \binom{n}{m} f^{(m)}(x_0)g^{(n-m)}(x_0)$$

I understood that

Step 1: $P_{n=1}$ ...

Step 2: We assume $P_n$ to be true

Step 3: We consider $P_{n+1}$ such as:

$$P_{n+1}:(fg)^{(n+1)}= \left[\sum_{m=0}^{n} \binom{n}{m} f^{(m)}g^{(n-m)} \right]^{(1)}$$

$$P_{n+1}:(fg)^{(n+1)}= \sum_{m=0}^{n} \binom{n}{m} \left[f^{(m)}g^{(n-m)} \right]^{(1)}$$

My question regards those last 2 lines written above. Why can we do that? Is there a property associated to the sum justifying this move? What is the intuition?

Comment: That the derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivatives is explained in every single calculus textbook on existence.

Comment: Since we have a sum with a finite number of terms, we can apply the additivity of derivatives, $(\sum_k f_k)' = \sum_k f_k'$. Hade it been a series, i.e. a sum with an infinte number of terms, we would not be allowed to do this without further knowledge about the convergence.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative operator is linear, which is to say $(\lambda f + \mu g)'(x) = \lambda f'(x) + \mu g'(x)$, for $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$; this just this rule applied $n+1$ times.